# Realloc couldn't allocate memory when used in loop

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I am trying to implement Simpson 1/3 rule in C and facing a problem with using malloc inside a for loop.

My current implementation is

```
int integrateSimpson(Integrate *intereg)
{
int i, j, iLoop, last;

double *tempOne = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 1);
double *tempTwo = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 1);

double dx, sumOdd, sumEven, area;

double lowerLimit = intereg->lowerLimit;
double upperLimit = intereg->upperLimit;
int *intervals = intereg->intervals;
int nIntervals = intereg->nIntervals;
int method = intereg->method;

for(j = 0; j < nIntervals; j++ )
{
    printf("Number of Intervals: %d",nIntervals);
    for(iLoop = 0; iLoop < nIntervals; iLoop++){
        printf("\nIntervals: %d", intervals[iLoop]);
    }
    tempOne = (double *) realloc(tempOne, sizeof(double) * intervals[j]);
    tempTwo = (double *) realloc(tempTwo, sizeof(double) * intervals[j]);
    if(tempTwo == NULL || tempOne == NULL)
    {
        TRACE("Could not realloc memory to temporary arrays");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(intervals[j] % 2 != 0)
    {
        TRACE("Found odd interval, adding 1 to make it even");
        intervals[j] = intervals[j] + 1;
    }

    dx = (upperLimit - lowerLimit) / intervals[j];
    for(i = 0; i <= intervals[j]; i++)
    {
        tempOne[i] = lowerLimit + i * dx;

        tempTwo[i] = intereg->func(tempOne[i]);
    }

    sumOdd = 0;
    sumEven = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < intervals[j]; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 1)
        {
            sumOdd +=  tempTwo[i];
        }
        else
        {
            sumEven += tempTwo[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\nPassed %d time", j );
    last = intervals[j] - 1;
    area = dx / 3 * (tempTwo[0] + tempTwo[last] + 4 * sumOdd + 2 * sumEven);
    intereg->areaUnderCurve[j]  = area;
    intereg->resultMatrix[method - 1][j] = intereg->areaUnderCurve[j];
}

free(tempOne);
tempOne = NULL;

free(tempTwo);
tempTwo = NULL;
return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

I tried to debug this and found that for `intervals = {2,8,16,64}` the loop works fine for the first time even the realloc part but with the second iteration for some reason, realloc doesn't work and I get a segmentation fault. I tried to reproduce this problem in the following way but the code below works fine

```
int i;
double *temp;

/* Initial memory allocation */
temp = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*1);

/* Reallocating memory */
for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
   temp = (double *) realloc(temp, sizeof(double)* i);
}
free(temp);
temp = NULL;
```

I know that realloc basically assigns a new memory at the same time frees the memory pointed by the pointer passed to it. But what is wrong that I am doing here?
Also is it a good way to use malloc with loops?

Any lead is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Obvious thing to check `intervals` is valid and `intervals[j]` is initialized.

Comment: @John3136 Yes I checked the nIntervals is fine, intervals is fine too with desired values of intervals getting printed in the loop just above the realloc moreover, they are integers, so should be fine in any case. I have made some changes to question please have a loop

Comment: Apart from what @John3136 says, be cautious about the values of `intervals[j]` as well as there's a chance for a multiplication overflow. If that happens later in the code you might access memory you've never allocated which would also create a seg fault.

Comment: @aep definitely, I'll keep this in mind once I get through this, Thanks for the input.

Comment: Problem would seem to be in the code you've skipped via `...Some Code...`

Comment: @John3136 I am stuck on this for 4 hours, the whole function is here!

Comment: This doesn't seem right: `for(i = 0; i <= intervals[j]; i++)`.

Comment: What's wrong with it? @dyukha

Comment: `tempTwo[intervals[j]]` isn't right. This along with what @dyukha mentioned is definitely an out-of-bound access.

Comment: You access index outside of bounds, like aep has shown.

Comment: Consider using `valgrind`

Comment: `realloc()` can fail, and you're not checking for that.   If it returns `NULL`, the previously allocated memory must be released.   Also, you are explicitly casting the returned values from `malloc()` and `realloc()`, and it appears there is no `#include <stdlib.h>`.   The combined effect is undefined behaviour (since, without `<stdlib.h>` (directly or indirectly) the compiler assumes `malloc()` and `realloc()` return `int` - and a pointer is not guaranteed to survive a round trip of conversions (pointer to int and back)).

Comment: Are you hinting towards memory leak? @jxh

Comment: `valgrind` would have detected out of bound accesses.

Comment: @Peter I do have the header included, also I have added checks for realloc by taking a temporary pointer and assigning it to tempOne if it not NULL! I suppose this the check you're talking about ?

Comment: @aep Yes, there was an out of bound access. Updated the code but the problem still remains!

Comment: @Milind - The checks you're doing result in the function returning, and will cause a leak if there is an error in `realloc()`.    The code you have posted does not `#include <stdlib.h>`.   There is also an off-by-one error in one of your `for` loops.  Look carefully at `for(i = 0; i <= intervals[j]; i++)`

Comment: @Peter Thanksyou! Fixed it! Working fine now! :) Can you please post it as an answer so that I can upvote? Also can you please throw some light on how realloc was failing by OOB access? I suspect I was corrupting the memory, is it?

Comment: Accessing a value past the end of an array can mean accessing memory that doesn't exist.  Although it's more common for writing to non-existent memory to cause a problem, reading from non-existent memory can too.

Comment: Got that! @Peter